# .Net Eazfuscator or any other Symbols renaming

Tags: .net, obfuscation, eazfuscator

The default command line build string of the last Free Eazfuscator produces buggy output for my project. Is there any way to disable complex obfuscation and use just renaming names? Or recommend any other Free simple .Net obfuscator.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ConfuserEx](https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx/releases).

It is really simple.

You can find the complete documentation [here](https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx/wiki/Documentation).

For a quick start go to [here](https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx/wiki/Basic-Usage).

To rename names you can use [Name Protection](https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx/wiki/Name-Protection) rule.